# MOD04_L2 data processing in r

Tags: raster, r, modis, batch, values

i am new to using r, so i excuse in advance for asking basic question. I have been trying to convert MOD04_L2 data into GeoTIFF and extract value to a district shapefile in R. the coding seems to work well but the raster area and the shapefile do not align as the raster in its metadata shows true extent but when I try to plot it or convert it totally changed. also the raster has no projection. I have attached the codes. plz, take a look at the codes.....
[thsis is the converted file of MOD04_L2 AOD data]

```
library (raster)
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)
setwd("C:\\Users\\hinay\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\dust storm 22 may 2020\\hdf AOD and AEDB\\rstudio")
files <- dir(pattern = ".hdf")
files
#for AOD
filename <- substr(files, 1, 4)
filename <- paste0("AODcomb", filename, ".tif")
i <-1
for (i in 1:4){
  sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i])
  gdal_translate(sds [64], dst_dataset = filename[i])
}
#for mosaicing AOD
raster1 <- raster("AODcomb24-12-2018 (1).hdf.tif")
raster2 <- raster("AODcomb24-12-2018.hdf.tif")
mi <- mosaic(raster1, raster2, fun=mean)
mi
plot(mi)
raster::writeRaster(mi, "AODcomb24-12-2018.tif")
#opening of shapefile
punjab <- readOGR("C:\\Users\\hinay\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\laads daac L2 data monthly\\district.shp")
plot(punjab)
reference <- punjab
crs(reference)
# projecting and cropping AOD
listAOD <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\hinay\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\laads daac L2 data monthly\\yearly data\\2018\\december 2018\\AOD december 2018", pattern = ".tif", full.names = T)
s2 <- stack(listAOD, quick=T)
projection(s2) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "
x1 <- crop(s2, reference)
y1 <- projectRaster(x1, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 ", filename = "proAOD.tif")
# a raster brick is formed
#now extraction of values
valuesAOD <- extract(y1, punjab, fun = mean, na.rm = T)
View(valuesAOD)
```

Comment: I think we're going to struggle with this for you. We don't have your data and you've not shown us any summary data or plots or maps. The best questions - ones that are most likely to get answered - are those where we can cut and paste the code and reproduce your error. We can stare at the code for eternity if the problem is in the data.

Comment: i guess i have sorted the issue....... the converted.tif file has a different cell size due to which the raster does not allign with the shapefile. is there any way we can set the raster resolution while converting it using gdal_translate??

Comment: Glad you fixed it. If you can't find out how to do that then I suggest you ask it as a new question with some clear sample data and a good description of what you expect to get as output. You could add your solution as an answer to the question now, or if you think it wouldn't help anybody else then you should probably delete this question.